# Will the 595 shift register burn out if outputs are always high?

Tags: components

I'm working with a [SainSmart 8-Channel Relay Module](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0057OC5WK) and I'm powering it via a 595 shift register via raspberry pi. The issue I'm having is that these sain boards activate the relay when the input is low and deactivate when high so essentially I have to turn the output high to turn the relays off and vice versa.

My question is whether or not this setup will cause long term issues with the pi or shift registers since the relays will be off the majority of the time. If so, what needs to be done to prevent issues?

I'm powering the shift registers via external 5v 1a source, not from the pi.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There should be almost zero current being drawn from the 595 while the outputs are high, so it shouldn't be an issue.  If the relays were active on a HIGH, then you would have to look at the current being drawn from the 595 for the relays coils and, using the datasheet specs, compare that to the "per output" MAX current compared to the current that the relays required.   There should be per pin and per package current spec. If the total amount of current being sourced or sunk does not exceed the 595's datasheet specs, you will be fine.

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/8oMAl.jpg